# CloudFlare SSL redirection loops

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare, iredmail

We have installed on one server a regular web-site (`http://example.com`) and web-mail (`https://example.com/mail`), Debian, Joomla, NGINX, iRedMail.

For protection from DDoS we use CloudFlare in free variant.

So the problem is: when CF is turned off everything is OK - site and web-mail is accessible. But when turning on CF-protection - site is OK, but web-mail says "too many redirects" in SSL.

Tried to set up as described [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218890817-Fixing-redirect-loops-when-using-Flexible-SSL) - nothing changes.

Seems like some misconfiguration in redirection rules in CF rules, or ngnix - can't understand. But where?

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` (web-site):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;.
   }

    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
        return 403;
        error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
        expires 1y;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
        expires 14d;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/redirect_to_https.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com_443` (web-mail):

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mail.example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-R
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem;

    index index.php index.html;

location / {
    root /opt/www/roundcubemail;
}

 # Web applications.
include /etc/nginx/templates/roundcube.tmpl;
include /etc/nginx/templates/iredadmin.tmpl;
include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
```

}

CF Rules:

```
https://example.com/mail SSL:Flexible - Full
```

When enabling CF protection of `example.com` (DNS A-record)  `mail.example.com` falls into a redirect loop.

Comment: Please include your nginx configuration and Cloudflare rules in your question. Please also include the exact redirects that are happening when logging in. You can see those in browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in DNS-records on cloudflare service. It was something like:

```
...
example.com. 300 IN A 1.2.3.4
www          300 IN A 1.2.3.4
mail         300 IN A 1.2.3.4
...
```

Changed A-records to CNAME like this:

```
...
example.com.      300 IN A 1.2.3.4
www.example.com.  300 IN CNAME example.com.
mail.example.com. 300 IN CNAME example.com.
...
```

did the thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to direct everything in CF's DNS to an IP address without a problem, you just need to disable it going through the cache - as CF does not accept any other protocol other than HTTP and HTTPS. so you are able to PR these back to A records and just disable the little orange cloud next the the entry.

Hope this helps.

> Here is an example of how DNS can be setup. Point everything you want going through CF caches with the orange cloud enabled, and everything you don't without it enabled. This allows A records to bypass it completely as explained above. I have shown it with aliases for the sake of administrative ease, but if you do a DNS lookup you get the exact same thing. [image: Cloudflare DNS Settings]

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: @Tim I have updated above an example of what I am referring to.

Comment: What you've said is mostly correct, but it's unclear and it doesn't properly answer the question. Why are you saying CloudFlare only supports http/s when that's what the question is asking about? Yes you can disable the cache for any record, but that doesn't address the question, and with the grey cloud you don't get page rules, DDOS protection, or caching, CF acts as a DNS server. You've used the abbreviation PR without explanation. It may be an answer to the question, but it's not a good answer.

Comment: Sorry I miss read the question slightly - I agree yes that CF would need to be enabled for webmail yes. If it is just the webmail aspect then its not a problem / I had read it as an MX issue... :S